# Send a file with payload using curl in Perl

Tags: perl, curl

I am trying to post an image to tinyping.com, but I need this to be done inside PERL without shelling out to curl.  This command works great.

```
curl -i --user api:****** --data-binary @myImage.png https://api.tinypng.com/shrink
```

How would I express this using LWP library in Perl?  I am very basic in Perl.

So far I have:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;


my $img_target_dir = ...;
my $imgname = ...;

#### 
  #not sure if i need to convert to BASE64
  open (IMAGE, "$img_target_dir$imgname") or die "$!";
  $raw_string = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE>; };
  $encoded = MIME::Base64::encode_base64( $raw_string );
####
my $content = post(
    "https://api:***************************\@api.tinypng.com/shrink", 
    Content_Type => 'image/png', 
        Content =>[
        ]
) or die print "failure\n";
```

Comment: LWP::UserAgent will do the work of grabbing the raw image data for you. [Here's a snippet](http://0paste.com/6223) from a screenshot script I wrote a while back.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just shelling out to curl. Works great.

```
    ###### tinyPNG.com ######
    my @file = "$img_target_dir$imgname";
    print "Sending the PNG for compression at tinyPNG.com\n";
    my $curl = `/usr/local/bin/curl -ki --user api:**************** --data-binary @"@file" https://api.tinypng.com/shrink`;
    $curl=~ /Location: (.*)/;
    my $url = "$1";
    print "Image Compressed At: $url</b>\n";
    my $curl2 = `/usr/local/bin/curl -k "$url" > "@file"`;
    chmod(0775, "@file");
    #########################
```